# Get element from UIWebView Swift iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm getting the URL of web page just fine by using:

```
print(webView.request?.mainDocumentURL)
```

I would want to know how can I get an element from the UIWebView., like path and id (image attached below) I tried extracting it with:

```
let html = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementsByName('json')")
```

Tho it didn't work.

[image: Screenshot of web page]
[image: Inspect Element of web page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response I was getting was JSON(Picture in question), used shouldStartLoadWithRequest UIWebView delegate and made it to identify the callback url and extract data then converted it to dictionary. 
'prefs' are NSUserDefaults, you can ignore.

```
    func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        do {
            return try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    return nil
}


func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    let fullNameArr = request.URL!.absoluteString.characters.split{$0 == "?"}.map(String.init)
    let callbackUrl = fullNameArr[0];
    if callbackUrl  == "http://xxxxxxxxxxx:2403/auth/google/callback" {

        webView.stopLoading();
        let url = NSURL(string: request.URL!.absoluteString)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in

            let datastring = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let responsedata = self.convertStringToDictionary(datastring as! String);

            let userId = responsedata!["uid"]! as! String
            let sessionId = responsedata!["id"]! as! String

            if(sessionId != "") {

                prefs.setObject(userId, forKey: "USERNAME")
                prefs.setObject(sessionId, forKey: "SESSIONID")
                prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                prefs.synchronize()

                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

            } else {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sign in Failed!", message: "Failed to retrieve data", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in }
                    alertController.addAction(OKAction)
                    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) { }
                })
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.webView.removeFromSuperview()
                self.navigationBar.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    return true
}
```